# Docusign CLM, can anyone please explain how CLM works, from configuring variables to using them in workflows & how they can be accessed in Templates?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Not able to understand how variables from salesforce are accessed in Docusign CLM workflows, Forms and Forms Library? what is complete step by step flow/path from accessing the variables from salesforce object and getting them in to the required Templates under Documents in Docusign CLM (Spring CM)?

Can anyone please send reference links or videos to understand Docusign CLM (Spring CM) from configuring variables to using them in workflows and how they can be accessed in Templates under the documents?

How workflows are configured and Variables are found under Params and how are the variables configured/used in the Templates under the Documents?

what is the significance of Forms and Forms Library in Document Generation Tab and how are they used in configuring workflows and Templates ??

Answer (score 0):

Forms are designed to query data in Salesforce from context of a single record (but can query records related to that initial context). On their own, this is all the forms do- collect information (in this case from Salesforce, and presumably also some information from the user that was perhaps not in Salesforce).
After next, that data is effectively the "Palette of Information" that can then be used to merge into a document. This is done by setting the Document Generation Configuration that matches up the Form (the query and user input data) with a document template (which contains the rules for where to place that data).
What that configuration can also be set to do is Start a workflow, and in doing so passes in that same palette of information. At this point, it is up to them to decide what happens with the data.
Regarding form field libraries- this is just a way to not have to build the forms (queries) from scratch each time. You can build the Form Library fields to query a particular data point from a specific context (e.g., I want to query to *Name* of the contact from context of the Contact record. This assumes that the user will be calling up the form from the context of the *contact*, and the query will grab the name. You do this because you might have several different forms and document types that all require the name of the contact, and you wouldn't want to have to do that every time you needed a new form. This also doesn't have to be just queried fields, and can also include those "User Input" fields we expect to reuse on a workflow (e.g., "what is the priority of this contract"? Low, Medium, High})

Inherently, a workflow starts with no data unless it is given the data, or is queried from within the workflow (which requires knowing what we want to query)

Summarized:

---

Salesforce Record - System of record/source data
Doc Gen Form - Query records for data, collect user input
Template - Decide which of the collected data points gets merged onto the document
Workflow - Can be set to receive the data from above after the merge takes place so "something else" can be done. Can query for additional data if the right parameters are available, and the query is defined.

**Additional note-** with custom Apex from Salesforce, the doc gen form experience can be skipped entirely, and an xml payload (within the request JSON Body) can be passed over API directly to Workflow.
Doc Gen is the Optional (but most common) middleman because it leverages the UI to build a query of data we need for the workflow, whereas SFDC Record -->Workflow is always custom (i.e., we have no product mechanism to configure a button in Salesforce that queries the SFDC Data and pass it straight to workflow)